# ReactJS & Redux: получить состояние только для 1-ой кнопки

Tags: reactjs, redux

Добрый день, у меня есть 2 одинаковые кнопки которые работают в разных контейнерах. Вопрос в следующем, как сделать так что бы кнопки работали не зависимо от друг друга? Т.е. Работали по отдельности. Данные кнопки вставляю через контейнеры.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код кнопки:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class QuantityLoader extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className={this.props.isQuantityLoader ? 'quantity-loader models' : 'quantity-loader products'}>
                <a onClick={() => this.props.changeQuantityLoader(!this.props.isQuantityLoader)}>
                    <IconFont name="exchange" size="2x" />
                </a>
                <p>{this.props.isQuantityLoader ? 'Model' : 'Product'} <span className="item-numbers">{this.props.isQuantityLoader ? '2' : '8'}</span></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default QuantityLoader;
```

Container:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {quantityLoaderFunc} from '../../actions/quantity';
import QuantityLoader from './QuantityLoader';

const mapStateToProps = ({app: {isQuantityLoader}}, ownProps) => {
    return {
        isQuantityLoader,
        ...ownProps
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeQuantityLoader (property) {
            quantityLoaderFunc(property)(dispatch);
        }
    }
};

const QuantityLoaderContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(QuantityLoader);

export default QuantityLoaderContainer;
```

Action:

```
import {changeQuantityLoader} from '../config/actionEvents';

export function quantityLoaderFunc (value) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: changeQuantityLoader,
            state: {
                isQuantityLoader: value
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

import {changeQuantityLoader} from '../config/actionEvents';

const defaultState = {
  isQuantityLoader: false
};

export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case changeQuantityLoader:
      return update(state, {isQuantityLoader: {$set: action.state.isQuantityLoader}});

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так они ведь подписаны на одно состояние в redux. Либо раздели их в redux state, либо для кнопок сделай внутренний state компонента, тогда они ни как не будут пересекаться.
При разделении state в redux, можешь передавать в редусер уникальное название кнопки, или название контейнера в котором используешь, по ней как раз добавлять новое значение в кувгч state(для того, что бы не дублировать action и reduc..)